# Assigning categories based on cell containing a string

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, libreoffice

I would like to fill in the category cell of this example

```
Date        Description    Debit    Category

15/07/2011  Farmer Smith    10
```

based on an other worksheet containing mapping values like this :

```
Farmer  | Groceries
```

I think I have to use a VLOOKUP but it doens't seem to "search" for the term ( farmer ) inside the Description cell, how do I tell my VLOOKUP to search the cell if it CONTAINS the first value and the mapping table and return the second column ( groceries ) .

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding OpenOffice Calc: AFAIK you can't modify the behaviour of **[`VLOOKUP`](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_VLOOKUP_function)** so it uses a CONTAINS check to determine the matching row. But if the relevant word is the the first one in the `Description` column in every case, you could "prepare" the lookupvalue (the first argument of the VLOOKUP function) so it just uses the first word to look for. A solution may look like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(B2, FIND(" ", B2)-1), $Sheet2.$A$2:$B$4, 2, 0)
```

(assuming `Sheet2.A2:B4 contains the lookup array). Split on multiple lines:

```
=VLOOKUP(
    LEFT(
        B2,
        FIND(
            " ",
            B2
        ) -1),
    $Sheet2.$A$2:$B$4,
    2,
    0
)
```

The first word of the `Description` column is determined using [**`LEFT`**](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_LEFT_function) and [**`FIND`**](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_FIND_function).

So, with the following category table:

[image: categories]

you would get the following result:

[image: result]